# How to do Reverting in GIT?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-revert

I am learning GIt.
I have 2 branches Prepod and Master. Working branch is prepod . 
I have commited the code on friday from prepod to master and i think there is some problem in the code.

so i have to put the code of Thursday of prepod to master.

Can anyone help.

Thanks.
Prat

Answer (score -1):

It is very important that you learn the `git language`. Read the `git help git` or `git help --web git` and the tutorial and the linked introductiory pages.

You don't commit from prepod to master for example, but you "merge the commits " from (branch) prepod into (the branch) master.

You can see the log of your current HEAD with `git log`, see `git help log` on this!

In the log you can see the commit hashes that are used to address commits.

With these hashes you can `git reset COMMIT` any branch to any status you have in your repository.